# Angular 9 npm install on version with ^ in package.json does not retrieve latest version locally

Tags: angular, npm

In my package.json I have the entry `"@servicestack/client":"^1.0.31"`.
The latest available version of servicestack is `1.0.48` at the moment.

When I run `npm install` locally, it will install the version `1.0.31`. On our deployment machine it will install `1.0.48`. I have cleared my local cache with `npm clean cache --force` with no success.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing it to retrieve a different version locally than on our deployment system? Makes you realize why you should use `npm ci` to use the package-lock.json file configuration.

Comment: What installed version does it show in the lockfile?

Comment: It shows the version `1.0.31`.

Comment: If you delete your local node_modules and install again, what do you get?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have removed the whole folder. It will create the new node_modules folder with the version `1.0.31` for servicestack.

Comment: @Userino try deleting your package-lock.json as well and then reinstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json documentation.

The ^ indicate a compatible version. Hence the 1.0.31 and the 1.0.48 are possibly compatible.

To force a version, try:

```
> "@servicestack/client":"1.0.48" (Only the .48 version) 
or
> "@servicestack/client":">=1.0.48"(.48 version and above).
```

if it fails, I suggest to delete package-lock each time you run a npm install, since it sometimes conflicts and keep your last version.

You can do it automatically in your package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "cleanPackageLock": "del /F /Q package-lock.json",
    "preinstall": "npm run cleanPackageLock"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should manually delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and then execute the following command:

```
npm install
```

It should re-generate the package-lock.json. Hope that it would work for you!